# If at least one checkbox of the first table is not checked then any checkbox of the second table can not be checked using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have two tables, each with some dynamically created checkbox in each row. Here is my code which I write in jsp:

```
<%
List<division> gd = (List<division>)request.getAttribute("gd");     
%>
<table style="float:left">
<tr><th>Divisions</th></tr>
<%
if(gd!=null && gd.size()>0){
    for(division di:gd){
%>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="p_div" value="<%=di.getDiv() %>"  onchange="func1()">
  <center><%=di.getDiv() %></center></td>
</tr>
<%
   }
}
%>
</table>
<%
List<roll> gr = (List<roll>)request.getAttribute("gr");     
%>
<table style="float:right" id="tab2">
<tr><th>Roll Nos.</th></tr>
<%
if(gr!=null && gr.size()>0){
    for(roll di1:gr){
%>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="p_roll" value="<%=di1.getRoll() %>" onchange="this.form.submit()" disabled>
  <center><%=di1.getRoll() %></center></td>
</tr>
<%
   }
}
%>
</table>
```

Here user can not check any checkbox of right side table if he/she doesn't check any checkbox of the left side table. I want to solve this problem using pure JavaScript.
I am trying this code for last couple of days. Please help
I have tried the below code:

```
function func1(){
    document.getElementById('tab2').getElementByTagName('input').disabled = false;
}
```

But still not working

Comment: won't you want to show the generated HTML of this ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please add more details like html (not template) and css in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll('[name=p_div]:checked').length` to  checked the length of checked checkboxes and if length is `> 0` disable/enable inputs in your next table .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function func1() {
  var flag = true;
  //checked chekcboxes length..
  if (document.querySelectorAll('[name=p_div]:checked').length > 0) {
    flag = false;
  }
  //loop through other input in next table
  document.querySelectorAll('[name=p_roll]').forEach(function(el) {
    el.disabled = flag; //enabled /disabled..
  });
  console.log("Total checked.." + document.querySelectorAll('[name=p_div]:checked').length)
}
```

```html
<table style="float:left">
  <tr>
    <th>Divisions</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="p_div" value="Abc" onchange="func1()">
      <center>
        Abc
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="p_div" value="Abc2" onchange="func1()">
      <center>
        Abc2
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>

<table style="float:right" id="tab2">
  <tr>
    <th>Roll Nos.</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="p_roll" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" disabled>
      <center>
        1
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="p_roll" value="2" onchange="this.form.submit()" disabled>
      <center>
        2
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: The answer suggested by @Swati works totally works totally fine. but when I am using very old version of chrome or firefox or explorer, it is not working. Please suggest me some conventional way to do this. it will be very helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

For older browsers

Either use

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('[name=p_roll]')]
```

to allow the forEach OR use a normal for loop

Also delegate

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("tab1").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var tgt = e.target; 
    if (tgt.name==="p_div") {
      var flag = document.querySelectorAll('[name=p_div]:checked').length === 0;
      console.log(flag)
      //loop through other input in next table
      var pRoll = document.querySelectorAll('[name=p_roll]')
      for (var i = 0; i < pRoll.length; i++) {
        pRoll[i].disabled = flag; //enabled /disabled..
      }
      console.log("Total checked..", document.querySelectorAll('[name=p_div]:checked').length)
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<table id="tab1" style="float:left">
  <tr>
    <th>Divisions</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="p_div" value="Abc">
      <center>
        Abc
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="p_div" value="Abc2">
      <center>
        Abc2
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>

<table style="float:right" id="tab2">
  <tr>
    <th>Roll Nos.</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="p_roll" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" disabled>
      <center>
        1
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="p_roll" value="2" onchange="this.form.submit()" disabled>
      <center>
        2
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```